# Compare NSNumber with NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnumber, nsinteger

I spent some time today chasing down two bugs, and ended up fixing both of them using the same solution.

Now that I have the solution, I was hoping to get some clarity behind it.

I'm comparing an attribute from Core Data (Integer 16/NSNumber) with an Integer (ABPropertyID & ABMultiValueIdentifier).

The bug was in this comparison, and oddly enough, only showed itself after I had killed the app (from the background tray), reopened it, and run through the same process that included the comparison.  Anyways...

This is what stopped working after a restart:

`if (myNumber.aProperty == [NSNUmber numberWithInt:anInteger]) { /* do stuff here */ }`

And these are the two solutions, which so far, are working perfectly:

`if ([myNumber.aProperty integerValue] == anInteger) {/* do stuff here */ }`

`if ([myNumber.aProperty isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:anInteger]]) { /* do stuff here */ }`

To me, they all look identical.  I'm always either converting the NSNumber to an integerValue, or converting the integer to an NSNumber.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use `==` to compare `NSNumber`s. Most of the time you'll be comparing two distinct objects, so the comparison won't evaluate to true. If you look at your if condition, notice that you're particularly comparing your property to a *brand new* `NSNumber` object.

Since `NSInteger` is a Cocoa wrapper for certain value types, comparing `NSInteger`s with `==` works fine.

The implementation of `isEqualToNumber:` probably takes the wrapped value types and compares them too.

Comment: That makes sense.  One thing that was weird though, and briefly mentioned in my post, is that the comparison was in fact working when I'd run my app for the first time.  It was only after I killed my app, reopened it, and ran the app through the comparison that I started seeing unexpected results.  Without knowing anything about my app or seeing any code, would you have any guesses as to why this was occurring?

Comment: @djibouti33: Not a clue... (and by saying this I'm pointing out its unpredictability too :)

Answer (score 2):

As you said, both solutions are working...

I would prefer the first one, as it appears more readable, IMHO...
It may also be more performant, as you are comparing integers, after having converted a NSNumber to an int.

In the second one, you convert an int to an object, then you compare the two objects...
So that's a second method call, which you don't have in the first case...

Hope this helps... : )

Answer (score 1):

`netWorkingButtonsIndexes` is the array which holds objects and
`LinkedIn` is a number with `int` data type.

```
[[netWorkingButtonsIndexes objectAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:LinkedIn]]
```

By using the `isEqual` method we can compare objects with any data rtype.